# A faster way for creating aggregates in SAS SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I have a data set named test with variables region, X1, X2, X3, X4......X20.

I would like to take the aggregates of X1-X20 by region level. My code is as follow:

```
proc sql;
    create table test2 as
    select sum(X1) as X1, sum(X2) as X2,......, sum(X20) as X20
    from test
    group by region;
quit;
```

Would there a faster way to get the sum as opposed to manually typing the sum for 20 of each variables? Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use PROC MEANS?

Comment: Yep, I guess proc means is a much faster way of transforming the data with much lesser code. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use PROC SQL instead of PROC MEANS?

```
proc means noprint nway data=test ;
  class region ;
  var x1-x20;
  output out=test2 sum=;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

A good use case for SAS macros. [Here's a link to a tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sas/sas_macros.htm), but I also highly recommend [the purple Carpenter book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1629592684).

```
 %MACRO do_test2;
    proc sql;
        create table test2 as
        select 
            %DO i = 1 %TO 20;
              sum(X&i) as X&1
              %IF &i ^= 20 %THEN , ;
            %END;
        from test 
        group by region;
    quit;
%MEND;
```

As @user667489 points out, because the macro code is using a `%DO` loop, the code block must be defined as a named, invokable macro (`%MACRO do_test2 . . . %MEND`).  Once you've defined it as above, you call it like this:

```
%do_test2;
```

Since we have this requirement, we can take advantage of the situation and make the number of repetitions a parameter, in case you ever want to vary it.  Then the definition is:

```
 %MACRO do_test2(num_reps);
    proc sql;
        create table test2 as
        select 
            %DO i = 1 %TO &num_reps;
              sum(X&i) as X&1
              %IF &i ^= &num_reps %THEN , ;
            %END;
        from test 
        group by region;
    quit;
%MEND;
```

Which you would call like this:

```
%do_test2(20);
```

Comment: You need a `%macro` and a `%mend` in there if you want to use a `%do` loop.

Comment: Absolutely - thanks!  Can't believe I forgot that.  Fixing now.